# WPF checkboxes do not visualize the check mark with style and do without style

Tags: wpf

This is a WPF application with checkboxes spanning most of the horizontal space. Not all of them show the check marks, they appear to visualize the check mark for only those left of some pixel. 
Further, when not using style all checkboxes visualize all check marks.
It is unclear what is the problem.

Please show me how to fix the displaying of the un-visualized check marks.

I am using MVVM light.

Here is an example run
[image: Showing some check boxes without the check marks]

Here is the xaml

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="768" Width="1093">
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/WpfApplication3;component/WpfApplication3Dictionary.xaml"/>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Background>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource GridBGColor}"/>
        </Grid.Background>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="180" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="180" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="180" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="180" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="180" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="180" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <CheckBox Content="T001" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="15" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked_T001}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" />
        <CheckBox Content="T002" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="15" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked_T002}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" />
        <CheckBox Content="T003" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="15" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked_T003}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" />
        <CheckBox Content="T004" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="15" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked_T004}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" />
        <CheckBox Content="T005" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="15" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked_T005}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" />
        <CheckBox Content="T006" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="15" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked_T006}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="5" />
        <CheckBox Content="T007" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="15" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked_T007}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" />
        <CheckBox Content="T008" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="15" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked_T008}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" />
        <CheckBox Content="T009" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="15" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked_T009}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" />
        <CheckBox Content="T010" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="15" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked_T010}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" />
        <CheckBox Content="T011" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="15" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked_T011}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" />
        <CheckBox Content="T012" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="15" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked_T012}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="5" />
        <CheckBox Content="T013" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="15" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked_T013}" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0" />
        <CheckBox Content="T014" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="15" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked_T014}" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" />
        <CheckBox Content="T015" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="15" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked_T015}" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" />
        <CheckBox Content="T016" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="15" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked_T016}" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3" />
        <CheckBox Content="T017" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="15" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked_T017}" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="4" />
        <CheckBox Content="T018" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="15" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked_T018}" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="5" />
        <CheckBox Content="T019" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="15" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked_T019}" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="0" />
        <CheckBox Content="T020" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="15" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked_T020}" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" />
        <CheckBox Content="T021" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="15" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked_T021}" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="2" />
        <CheckBox Content="T022" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="15" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked_T022}" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="3" />
        <CheckBox Content="T023" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="15" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked_T023}" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="4" />
        <CheckBox Content="T024" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="15" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked_T024}" Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="5" />
        <CheckBox Content="T025" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="15" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked_T025}" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="0" />
        <CheckBox Content="T026" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="15" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked_T026}" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="1" />
        <CheckBox Content="T027" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="15" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked_T027}" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="2" />
        <CheckBox Content="T028" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="15" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked_T028}" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="3" />
        <CheckBox Content="T029" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="15" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked_T029}" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="4" />
        <CheckBox Content="T030" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="15" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked_T030}" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="5" />
        <CheckBox Content="T031" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="15" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked_T031}" Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="0" />
        <CheckBox Content="Toggle All Checkboxes" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="15" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked_T000}" Grid.Column="5" Grid.Row="5" />
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

here is the xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = new ViewModel.MainViewModel();
    }
}
```

Here is the viewmodel:

```
    public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the MainViewModel class.
    /// </summary>
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        ////if (IsInDesignMode)
        ////{
        ////    // Code runs in Blend --> create design time data.
        ////}
        ////else
        ////{
        ////    // Code runs "for real"
        ////}
    }

    private bool _IsChecked_T000 = true;
    public bool IsChecked_T000
    {
        get { return _IsChecked_T000; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _IsChecked_T000)
                return;

            _IsChecked_T000 = value;
            IsChecked_T001 = value;
            IsChecked_T002 = value;
            IsChecked_T003 = value;
            IsChecked_T004 = value;
            IsChecked_T005 = value;
            IsChecked_T006 = value;
            IsChecked_T007 = value;
            IsChecked_T008 = value;
            IsChecked_T009 = value;
            IsChecked_T010 = value;
            IsChecked_T011 = value;
            IsChecked_T012 = value;
            IsChecked_T013 = value;
            IsChecked_T014 = value;
            IsChecked_T015 = value;
            IsChecked_T016 = value;
            IsChecked_T017 = value;
            IsChecked_T018 = value;
            IsChecked_T019 = value;
            IsChecked_T020 = value;
            IsChecked_T021 = value;
            IsChecked_T022 = value;
            IsChecked_T023 = value;
            IsChecked_T024 = value;
            IsChecked_T025 = value;
            IsChecked_T026 = value;
            IsChecked_T027 = value;
            IsChecked_T028 = value;
            IsChecked_T029 = value;
            IsChecked_T030 = value;
            IsChecked_T031 = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private bool _IsChecked_T001 = true;
    public bool IsChecked_T001
    {
        get { return _IsChecked_T001; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _IsChecked_T001)
                return;

            _IsChecked_T001 = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private bool _IsChecked_T002 = true;
    public bool IsChecked_T002
    {
        get { return _IsChecked_T002; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _IsChecked_T002)
                return;

            _IsChecked_T002 = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private bool _IsChecked_T003 = true;
    public bool IsChecked_T003
    {
        get { return _IsChecked_T003; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _IsChecked_T003)
                return;

            _IsChecked_T003 = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private bool _IsChecked_T004 = true;
    public bool IsChecked_T004
    {
        get { return _IsChecked_T004; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _IsChecked_T004)
                return;

            _IsChecked_T004 = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private bool _IsChecked_T005 = true;
    public bool IsChecked_T005
    {
        get { return _IsChecked_T005; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _IsChecked_T005)
                return;

            _IsChecked_T005 = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private bool _IsChecked_T006 = true;
    public bool IsChecked_T006
    {
        get { return _IsChecked_T006; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _IsChecked_T006)
                return;

            _IsChecked_T006 = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private bool _IsChecked_T007 = true;
    public bool IsChecked_T007
    {
        get { return _IsChecked_T007; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _IsChecked_T007)
                return;

            _IsChecked_T007 = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private bool _IsChecked_T008 = true;
    public bool IsChecked_T008
    {
        get { return _IsChecked_T008; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _IsChecked_T008)
                return;

            _IsChecked_T008 = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private bool _IsChecked_T009 = true;
    public bool IsChecked_T009
    {
        get { return _IsChecked_T009; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _IsChecked_T009)
                return;

            _IsChecked_T009 = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private bool _IsChecked_T010 = true;
    public bool IsChecked_T010
    {
        get { return _IsChecked_T010; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _IsChecked_T010)
                return;

            _IsChecked_T010 = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private bool _IsChecked_T011 = true;
    public bool IsChecked_T011
    {
        get { return _IsChecked_T011; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _IsChecked_T011)
                return;

            _IsChecked_T011 = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private bool _IsChecked_T012 = true;
    public bool IsChecked_T012
    {
        get { return _IsChecked_T012; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _IsChecked_T012)
                return;

            _IsChecked_T012 = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private bool _IsChecked_T013 = true;
    public bool IsChecked_T013
    {
        get { return _IsChecked_T013; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _IsChecked_T013)
                return;

            _IsChecked_T013 = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private bool _IsChecked_T014 = true;
    public bool IsChecked_T014
    {
        get { return _IsChecked_T014; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _IsChecked_T014)
                return;

            _IsChecked_T014 = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private bool _IsChecked_T015 = true;
    public bool IsChecked_T015
    {
        get { return _IsChecked_T015; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _IsChecked_T015)
                return;

            _IsChecked_T015 = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private bool _IsChecked_T016 = true;
    public bool IsChecked_T016
    {
        get { return _IsChecked_T016; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _IsChecked_T016)
                return;

            _IsChecked_T016 = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private bool _IsChecked_T017 = true;
    public bool IsChecked_T017
    {
        get { return _IsChecked_T017; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _IsChecked_T017)
                return;

            _IsChecked_T017 = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private bool _IsChecked_T018 = true;
    public bool IsChecked_T018
    {
        get { return _IsChecked_T018; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _IsChecked_T018)
                return;

            _IsChecked_T018 = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private bool _IsChecked_T019 = true;
    public bool IsChecked_T019
    {
        get { return _IsChecked_T019; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _IsChecked_T019)
                return;

            _IsChecked_T019 = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private bool _IsChecked_T020 = true;
    public bool IsChecked_T020
    {
        get { return _IsChecked_T020; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _IsChecked_T020)
                return;

            _IsChecked_T020 = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private bool _IsChecked_T021 = true;
    public bool IsChecked_T021
    {
        get { return _IsChecked_T021; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _IsChecked_T021)
                return;

            _IsChecked_T021 = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private bool _IsChecked_T022 = true;
    public bool IsChecked_T022
    {
        get { return _IsChecked_T022; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _IsChecked_T022)
                return;

            _IsChecked_T022 = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private bool _IsChecked_T023 = true;
    public bool IsChecked_T023
    {
        get { return _IsChecked_T023; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _IsChecked_T023)
                return;

            _IsChecked_T023 = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private bool _IsChecked_T024 = true;
    public bool IsChecked_T024
    {
        get { return _IsChecked_T024; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _IsChecked_T024)
                return;

            _IsChecked_T024 = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private bool _IsChecked_T025 = true;
    public bool IsChecked_T025
    {
        get { return _IsChecked_T025; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _IsChecked_T025)
                return;

            _IsChecked_T025 = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private bool _IsChecked_T026 = true;
    public bool IsChecked_T026
    {
        get { return _IsChecked_T026; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _IsChecked_T026)
                return;

            _IsChecked_T026 = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private bool _IsChecked_T027 = true;
    public bool IsChecked_T027
    {
        get { return _IsChecked_T027; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _IsChecked_T027)
                return;

            _IsChecked_T027 = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private bool _IsChecked_T028 = true;
    public bool IsChecked_T028
    {
        get { return _IsChecked_T028; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _IsChecked_T028)
                return;

            _IsChecked_T028 = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private bool _IsChecked_T029 = true;
    public bool IsChecked_T029
    {
        get { return _IsChecked_T029; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _IsChecked_T029)
                return;

            _IsChecked_T029 = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private bool _IsChecked_T030 = true;
    public bool IsChecked_T030
    {
        get { return _IsChecked_T030; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _IsChecked_T030)
                return;

            _IsChecked_T030 = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private bool _IsChecked_T031 = true;
    public bool IsChecked_T031
    {
        get { return _IsChecked_T031; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _IsChecked_T031)
                return;

            _IsChecked_T031 = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

here is the style resource dictionary

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

<Color x:Key="GridBGColor">#FF1E1E1E</Color>
<Color x:Key="AccentColor">#FFCCDC00</Color>

<!-- CheckBox Style *******************************************************************************************-->
<Style x:Key="{x:Type CheckBox}" TargetType="CheckBox">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="CheckBox">
                <Viewbox>
                    <BulletDecorator Background="Transparent" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                        <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                            <Border x:Name="Border" Width="13" Height="13" CornerRadius="1" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="White">
                                <Image x:Name="CheckMark" Source="/WpfApplication3;component/checkmark2.png" Stretch="Uniform"/>
                            </Border>
                        </BulletDecorator.Bullet>

                        <ContentPresenter Margin="4,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                    </BulletDecorator>
                </Viewbox>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="CheckMark" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="{x:Null}">
                        <Setter TargetName="CheckMark" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                    </Trigger>

                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="DarkGray" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="DarkGray" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkGray"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Have you considered using an array or list of boolean values instead of variables for every property?  You could use an `ItemsControl` with a `UniformGrid` to simplify this down **significantly**.

Comment: I haven't. I can look into that. However, it seems the inclusion of the style causes check boxes not to display for ischecked==true

Comment: A quick test of your style on my system shows everything working fine. I didn't have your check mark icon though, so i just substituted a `Border` with a red background. I doubt that would affect the outcome though.

Comment: i did the same and it works! Thank you. make it an answer and i will accept it.

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/526724/bradley-uffner i did the same and it works! Thank you. make it an answer and i will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I am adding this answer, however, credit goes to Bradley Uffner.
The problem appears to be the use of the png file for the check mark. Changing the code to use XAML only corrects the problem and all check boxes show check marks.

Here is modified resource dictionary:

> 

```
<Color x:Key="GridBGColor">#FF1E1E1E</Color>
<Color x:Key="C3">#FF424242</Color>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="B3" Color="{StaticResource C3}"/>

<!-- CheckBox Style *******************************************************************************************-->
<Style x:Key="{x:Type CheckBox}" TargetType="CheckBox">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="CheckBox">
                <Viewbox>
                    <BulletDecorator Background="Transparent" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                        <BulletDecorator.Resources>
                            <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="CheckRadialColor" EndPoint="1,0" StartPoint="0,1">
                                <GradientStop Color="#FFFABF82" Offset="0" />
                                <GradientStop Color="#FFFC9100" Offset="0.1" />
                                <GradientStop Color="#FFFFC577" Offset="1" />
                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                        </BulletDecorator.Resources>
                        <BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                            <Canvas Width="16" Height="16" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                <Border x:Name="Border" Canvas.Left="1.5" Canvas.Bottom="1.5" CornerRadius="3" Background="{StaticResource B3}" Height="13" Width="13"/>
                                <Path x:Name="CheckMark" Stroke="{StaticResource CheckRadialColor}" StrokeThickness="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="False" Data="M 2 6 L 8 12 M 6 12 L 15.5 1"/>
                            </Canvas>
                        </BulletDecorator.Bullet>
                        <ContentPresenter Margin="4,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
                    </BulletDecorator>
                </Viewbox>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="CheckMark" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="{x:Null}">
                        <Setter TargetName="CheckMark" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                    </Trigger>

                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="DarkGray" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="DarkGray" />
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DarkGray"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```